# php re-arrange array rows into columns to display in table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this array being returned by my db.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [dwg_id] => 1
        [sws_dwg_no] => 160-001
        [client_dwg_no] => KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/001
        [dwg_title] => OVERALL LAYOUT AND REFERENCE DRAWING
        [dwg_by] => JES
        [dwg_date] => 2016-03-11 16:13:00
        [dwg_rev] => A
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [dwg_id] => 1
        [sws_dwg_no] => 160-001
        [client_dwg_no] => KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/001
        [dwg_title] => OVERALL LAYOUT AND REFERENCE DRAWING
        [dwg_by] => JES
        [dwg_date] => 2016-04-04 21:41:31
        [dwg_rev] => B
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [dwg_id] => 2
        [sws_dwg_no] => 160-002
        [client_dwg_no] => KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/002
        [dwg_title] => OVERALL LAYOUT AND REFERENCE DRAWING
        [dwg_by] => JES
        [dwg_date] => 2016-03-11 16:13:00
        [dwg_rev] => A
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [dwg_id] => 2
        [sws_dwg_no] => 160-002
        [client_dwg_no] => KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/002
        [dwg_title] => OVERALL LAYOUT AND REFERENCE DRAWING
        [dwg_by] => JES
        [dwg_date] => 2016-04-04 21:41:31
        [dwg_rev] => B
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [dwg_id] => 3
        [sws_dwg_no] => 160-100
        [client_dwg_no] => KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/100
        [dwg_title] => CONCRETE WORK PLAN AND DETAIL
        [dwg_by] => JES
        [dwg_date] => 2016-03-11 16:13:00
        [dwg_rev] => A
    )
```

and I want to arrange the array in this order so I can populate the html table with the new array. The [0] row of the new array is the header of the table.

This is what the new array should look like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Drawing no.
        [1] => 160-001
        [2] => 160-002
        [3] => 160-100
        [4] => 160-101
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Client drawing no.
        [1] => KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/001
        [2] => KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/002
        [3] => KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/100
        [4] => KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/101
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Title
        [1] => OVERALL LAYOUT AND REFERENCE DRAWING
        [2] => OVERALL LAYOUT AND REFERENCE DRAWING
        [3] => CONCRETE WORK PLAN AND DETAIL
        [4] => CONCRETE WORK SECTION
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => By
        [1] => JES
        [2] => JES
        [3] => JES
        [4] => JES
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => 2016/04/04
        [2] => 2016/04/04
        [3] => 2016/03/11
        [4] => 2016/03/11
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => B
        [1] => 2016/04/04
        [2] => 2016/04/04
    )

   )
```

Here is my code that I have that works unto the revision date. $result is the input array from the db.

```
$new_array = array();
    if(count($result) > 0)
    {
        $dwg_no = array(0=>'Drawing no.') + array_column($result, 'sws_dwg_no', 'dwg_id');
        $client_dwg_no =array(0=> 'Client drawing no.') + array_column($result, 'client_dwg_no', 'dwg_id');
        $title = array(0=>'Title') + array_column($result,'dwg_title', 'dwg_id');
        $by = array(0=>'By') + array_column($result, 'dwg_by', 'dwg_id');       
        foreach($result as $row){
            $rev = $row['dwg_rev'];
            if($rev == $row['dwg_rev']){
                $rev_date[$row['dwg_id']] = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($row['dwg_date']));
            }
            elseif($rev >= $row['dwg_rev']) {
                $rev_date[$row['dwg_id']] = '';
            }

            ${'rev_'. $rev . '_date'} = array(0 => $rev) + $rev_date;
        }
        $new_array = array(
                        0 => $dwg_no,
                        1 => $client_dwg_no,
                        2 => $title,
                        3 => $by,
                        4 => ${'rev_'. $rev . '_date'});

    }
```

So the issues are

1. Arrange the revision dates under the correct revision. My code doesn't do that at the moment. Depending on how many times you refresh the page the dates change.
2. $new_array must be dynamic so that the number of revisions will not be limited. The revisions order is from A - Z and then 1 - 99

The table should look like this
[image]

Comment: Could you add an example of what this table will look like?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a matrix transpose

```
function transpose($array) {
   array_unshift($array, null);
   call_user_func_array('array_map', $array);
}
```

Before:

```
160-001 | 160-002 | 160-003 | 
KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/001 | KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/002 | KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/100 |
```

After:

```
160-001 | KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/001 | 
160-002 | KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/002 | 
160-003 | KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/100 |
```

Here's my full code:

```
<?php

$data = [
    ['160-001','160-002','160-003'],
    ['KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/001', 'KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/002 ', 'KSB/9972475771/WP5/02/100']
];

function transpose($array) {
        array_unshift($array, null);
        return call_user_func_array('array_map', $array);
}

foreach($data as $row) {
    foreach($row as $column) {
            echo $column . " | ";
    }
        echo "<br>";
}

$data = transpose($data);

foreach($data as $row) {
    foreach($row as $column) {
            echo $column . " | ";
    }
        echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: The code this link better describes how the table should work.  http://www.toppa.com/2008/making-an-html-table-using-arrays-of-column-data/

Comment: Thanks a lot. but it doesn't work if only one row. such as ```$data = [
    ['160-001','160-002','160-003']
];```